# Windows VS - Xamarin IOS info.plist Device Orientation Changes After Save

Tags: ios, windows, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Every time I go in to Info.plist in order to lock the app to Portrait orientation and save, my changes aren't saved.

For ex. 
I want [image: this]
Portrait checked.
I save.

When I open the file back up, i get [image: this]

I have a feeling that this is built in for a reason. But, it wouldn't surprise me if its a bug.

I wasn't able to find more info on this specific issue.

Comment: I have added a issue on github of Microsoft https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60604 . You can always pay attention

Comment: Actually just saw that you posted under VSCode. I am using Visual Studio. The github thread is closed.